# My structure array prints garbage after returning from a file

Tags: arrays, c, file, structure

I am very new to the C language and I am trying to read in lines from a file that contain a name and a phone number. I then need to dynamically allocate an array of a structure and fill that array with the name and number from the file. This works and when I print it out in the function that does this is works fine, but when I return the structure and try to print in `main` it prints question marks in boxes.

This is what a file will look like:

```
Aaron 7774013
Jon 7774014
Thomas 7774015
Matt 7774016
```

These are the relevant sections of code (if you need to see more let me know):

```c
struct _data {
    char *name;
    long number;
};

struct _data *LOAD(FILE *stream, int size) {
    char str[50];
    char *token;
    int i;
    struct _data *BlackBox = calloc(size, sizeof(struct _data));
    stream = fopen("hw4.data.txt", "r");
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        if (fgets(str, 50, stream) != NULL) {
            token = strtok(str, " ");
            BlackBox[i].name = token;
            printf("%s\n", BlackBox[i].name); //prints just fine
            puts(token);
            while (token != NULL) {
                token = strtok(NULL, " ");
                BlackBox[i].number = atoi(token);
                break;
            }   
        }
    }
    fclose(stream);
    return BlackBox;
}
```

This is in the `main` function

```
FILE *stream;

int size = scan(&stream);
struct _data *BlackBox = LOAD(stream, size);
for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    printf("%s\n", BlackBox[i].name);  //prints out garbage
}
```

Comment: `token = strtok(str, " "); BlackBox[i].name = token;` is not correct because`str` is a local variable. It becomes invalid as soon as the function exits. Allocate dynamic memory and then copy the string into the buffer (or use `strdup` as a short cut).

Comment: Furthermore, you are assigning the same `str` to multiple `BlackBox` entries. There's no way each entry will have a different string value - as a test, do the `printf` in a loop after the `for` loop and you will see that.

Answer (score 0):

`char str[50];` is a **local variable** at the moment you leave the function the memory allocated by your program is lost. **You can't acces it anymore**.

Fix : Don't allocate fix memory to str but dynamic.

I propose to create str from main and passing her adresse to LOAD then you will be able to modify the content of the adresse with LOAD.

Answer (score -1):

You make mistake in using the results of `strtok`. You had better copy the results to your own memory, instead of get the `char *` pointers only, like

```c
// This is only an example, remember to allocate large enough memory for
// `BlackBox[i].name` to save the content got from `token`
#define LEN 64

struct _data{
    char name[LEN];
    long number;
};
struct _data *BlackBox = calloc(size, sizeof(struct _data));

//...
token = strtok(str, " ");

// Instead of
//
// BlackBox[i].name = token;
//
// You should copy
strncpy(BlackBox[i].name, token, LEN-1);
```

You can refer to [strtok](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtok).

Comment: and you didnt allocate any memory, and strncpy is doubly wrong with strlen of source